# Get Detached Volume Date In Cloudtrail using rest api

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

Is there any api to get detached volumes date and time from aws cloud trail

Comment: Have you tried it? Start by detaching a volume, then going to the AWS CloudTrail management console to confirm that there is a trail record. (It might take a few minutes to appear.) Then, you can use the CloudTrail API to **lookup** that type of event. For example, here is the [Python SDK documentation for CloudTrail](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Client.lookup_events).

Comment: This information might be easier to obtain from **AWS Config**, which maintains a configuration history for resources. You could reference a specific Amazon EBS Volume and retrieve its historical configurations.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I'm able to see the logs through the cloud trail console. but I want to fetch logs data through Rest-API Call, Is there an API call to fetch the data from cloud trail?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If you knew an API to fetch cloud trail data ..please mention the request URL and query parameters

Comment: Which programming language do you use? I provided a link (above) to the Python SDK for CloudTrail. (It is better to use an SDK rather than a REST call.) For AWS Config, you could use: [GetResourceConfigHistory - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_GetResourceConfigHistory.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein we are using javascript and our own scripting language (Won't support SDK or any such dependencies). I can use the response and display it.

Comment: RESTful APIs are available for AWS CloudTrail and AWS Config. Please refer to the API [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com) for each service.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have referred this [document] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) there is no information provided about the request URL. Can you provide me the request URL along with the query parameter should i pass?

Comment: I think you would be better using the `lookup()` function of AWS Config. Basically, AWS Config keeps track of the configuration history of resources, while AWS CloudTrail stores information about the _event_ that caused a configuration change.